# How to Align this Three Column view to Centered two - column view?

Tags: html, css, alignment, center, responsive

How to align this Three Column view to Centered two - column view? 
I tried couple of things but I didn't manage to get it to work.

When its working, it's not responsive in smaller screens.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in Advance

**Screenshot**:

[I want this to two column centered view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgXo9.jpg).

You can also check out the following snippet:

```css
#aa-latest-property {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 100px 0;
}
#aa-latest-property .aa-latest-property-area {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
#aa-latest-property .aa-latest-property-area .aa-latest-properties-content {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}
.aa-properties-item {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.aa-properties-item:hover {
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px 3px #ccc;
}
.aa-properties-item .aa-properties-item-img {
  width: 100%;
}
.aa-properties-item .aa-properties-item-img img {
  width: 100%;
}
.aa-properties-item .aa-tag {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  top: -15px;
}
.aa-properties-item .for-rent {
  background-color: #20ceb3;
}
.aa-properties-item .sold-out {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
.aa-properties-item .aa-properties-item-content {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-top: none;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="aa-latest-property-area">

  <div class="aa-latest-properties-content">
    <div class="row">

      <h3>We create an environment for all the professionals where the work itself gets stimulated.</h3>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <article class="aa-properties-item">
          <a href="#" class="aa-properties-item-img">
            <img src="img/core.jpeg" alt="img">
          </a>

          <div class="aa-properties-item-content">

            <div class="aa-properties-about">
              <h3>Core Values</h3>
              <p>We are guided by the core values of: Professionalism, Transparent dealings, Integrity, Dedication, Commitment, Hard work, Fair play and ethical working…</p>
            </div>

          </div>
        </article>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <article class="aa-properties-item">
          <a href="#" class="aa-properties-item-img">
            <img src="img/core.jpeg" alt="img">
          </a>

          <div class="aa-properties-item-content">

            <div class="aa-properties-about">
              <h3>Core Values</h3>
              <p>We are guided by the core values of: Professionalism, Transparent dealings, Integrity, Dedication, Commitment, Hard work, Fair play and ethical working…</p>
            </div>

          </div>
        </article>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quick answer :
add .col-sm-6 class to this div

```
<div class="col-md-4">
```

to be

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
```

---

DETAILS :

in bootstrap you can make responsive columns using these classes :

```
.col-lg-#  /* for large screens */
.col-md-#  /* for medium screens */
.col-sm-#  /* for small screens */
.col-xs-#  /* for extra small screens */
```

the # is number between 1 and 12 and it is a ratio 
for example 
.col-md-12 will have a width of 100% on medium screens
and 
.col-sm-6 will have a width of 50% on small screens
and so on

---

full documntation : http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/

Comment: I want that two Column to be centered  in present size